# How to properly display a list of item in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Good day everyone,

This app works fine when running in my laptop, but when launched from my tablet, the following code leads to a connection error. I am assuming its because the following requires too much processing power for the tablet to handle. Hence, I am looking for ways to optimize the following code.

Essentially I am trying to display a list of item for the user to select. The list in this case is the longestdimensions such as 11, 18, 24.
I am using express app, and for the view I am using handlebars (hbs).

Below is the route code

```
connection.connect();


   // Run the query to retrieve the box name where the dimension of the box is equivilant to the computer name of the tablet
   // The computer name of the tablet should reflect the location of the box which is indentified by
  let sql = `SELECT box_id, longestDimension
           FROM box
           WHERE longestDimension != ''
           AND LOWER(box_id) = LOWER(?)`;
      connection.query(sql, computerName, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (!err) {
        // Check to see if the user entered code is found in the database
        // Create a variable to track if the item was found
         for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {

            var data = {
             rows: rows,
             userHashtag: userEnteredHashtag
            }
            res.render('delivery/chooseBox', data);

          }


    // If the query fails to execute
      } else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
          res.render('error/errorConnection', {});
      }
    });
    connection.end();
```

Below is the view code

```
{{#each rows}}
    <form method="post" action="/delivery/chooseBoxSelected">
        <input type="hidden" name="boxSelectedValue" value="{{this.box_id}}">
       <input type="hidden" name="boxSelectedDimension" value="{{this.longestDimension}}">
               <input type="hidden" name="userHashtag" value="{{userHashtag}}">

        <button class="btn-dimension" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp;Longest dimension {{this.longestDimension}}"
        </button>
    </form>
{{/each}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this server code on your tablet?  If so, why?

Comment: because the tablet i use as the user interface and connected to hardware product. I run other server code in this, but this is the one that causes issues.

Comment: OK, you're running node.js on the tablet.  What kind of tablet is it?  How much RAM in the tablet?  How big are the query results?  How big a page are you trying to create?

Comment: And why are you calling `res.render()` separately for every single row?  Shouldn't you collect the data from all the rows and then call `res.render()` just once?

Comment: That's probably a better idea to collect the data from all the rows and the call res.render().

Comment: In fact, I'm surprised that it doesn't cause an error to call `res.render()` more than once.  I think if you looked at the server logs, you would see an error.

Comment: res.render is only called once. It is placed twice, but only called if a condition is met

Comment: That's not what your code shows.  You have `res.render()` inside a `for` loop.

Comment: Oh thats because i want to render each item in the list throughout the for loop cycle

Comment: That's not how `res.render()` works.  You collect all your data and call it once to render the page.  Even worse, your code shows calling `res.render()` multiple times with the same data every time (not that the subsequent times would even do anything).  You need to fix that.

Comment: FYI, the `{{#each rows}}` in your template will expand each separate row into the HTML page.  You only call `res.render()` once, pass in the array of `rows` like you are and let the template render them all in one call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you should only call `res.render()` once rather than separately for each row.

```
  connection.query(sql, computerName, function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (!err) {
          // Check to see if the user entered code is found in the database
          var data = {
              rows: rows,
              userHashtag: userEnteredHashtag
          }
          res.render('delivery/chooseBox', data);

      // If the query fails to execute
      } else {
          console.log('Error while performing Query.');
          res.render('error/errorConnection', {});
      }
  });
```

The `{{#each rows}}` in your template will repeat for every row.  There is no need to call `res.render()` for each row.  In fact, doing so is just a waste and may even cause a server error.